# How to remove rows from dataframe based upon criteria in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with thousands of observations, and a few variables. I want to create a subset of this dataframe whereby I remove rows of no interest to me, based upon multiple conditions working in union.

For example if I wanted to perform the following:

Remove entries where *event_type* = 'A' or 'T' **and** *value* < 0,

how would one format this in R? (Where *event_type* and *value* are variables) Many thanks.

Comment: The and will be `&`, `=` to `==` if more number of elements on the rhs use `%in%` i.e. `subset(yourdata, event_type %in% c("A", "T") & value < 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dplyr response. Simply `filter` the data for the conditions indicated and the result should be what you're looking for.

```
library(dplyr)

df_filtered <- df %>%
   filter(event_type %in% c('A', 'T'),
          value < 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, use `subset`

```
subset(df1, event_type %in% c("A", "T") & value < 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This produces a dataframe of all the observations I want to remove, however how can I create a dataframe of the remaining observations that I want to keep?

Comment: I've just figured it out, so I may as well share it here anyway. I used the anti_join function from dplyr across the subset and original dataframe to create a filtered dataframe.